# Word wrap for NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, nsstring

I have NSMutableAttributedString and the string is pretty long. I would like to do word wrap while displaying it on the UIlabel. If it was NSString, i will go ahead and do something like this, 
[Dynamic UILabel truncating the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558956/dynamic-uilabel-truncating-the-text)
     But how can i do it with NSAttributedString ?
And once it is done, i need to resize the view depending on the label size.

Comment: Hey kBpro is my answser helpful to you. If yes accept it.

Answer (score 10):

The lineBreakMode property isn't deprecated in iOS 6. It has simply changed the names of the constants. The old constants are deprecated, but still available. You can use the new constants even if you are deploying to an older iOS, because the constants are just enum values. The old names and the new names have the same values. So, just set yourlabelname.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[attributedStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                     value:paragraphStyle
                     range:NSMakeRange(0,[attributedStr length])];
```

Comment: The OP asked for word wrapping, yet the voted reply truncates. Shouldn't this be `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`?

Answer (score 5):

Following also works irrespective of using `attributedText` or normal text. Make sure to add the below line ***after*** setting the `AttributedText` and font to the label.

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following property after updating the attributedText field:

```
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```