# How to programmatically change a UIView's "origin" (as labeled in Xcode)?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uikit

You will notice the red "+" / "arrows" glyph in the attached screenshot. It is easy enough to change this "origin" point in Xcode. Is there *also* a way to do this programmatically or is this entirely an Xcode abstraction?

[image]

For instance, I want to programmatically create a UILabel and position it by calculating the lower right hand coordinate. In Xcode, I would simply make sure that the red "+" is on the bottom right grid point and define the X, Y, Width and Height parameters with that "origin" in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're not using autolayout, you can position a label (or any view) in code by setting its center.  So if you know where you want the label's lower right corner to be, you can just subtract half the width and height of the label to compute where its center should be:

```
CGPoint lowerRight = somePoint;
CGRect frame = label.frame;
label.center = CGPointMake(lowerRight.x - frame.size.width / 2,
    lowerRight.y - frame.size.height / 2);
```

I would recommend just doing that.

But if you want, you can instead go to a lower level.  Every view has a Core Animation layer, which is what actually manages the view's on-screen appearance.  The layer has an `anchorPoint` property, which by default is (0.5, 0.5), representing the center of the layer.  You can set the `anchorPoint` to (1, 1) for the lower-right corner:

```
label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
```

Now the label's `center` actually controls the location of its lower right corner, so you can set it directly:

```
label.center = somePoint; // actually sets the lower right corner
```

You'll need to add the `QuartzCore` framework to your target and import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to modify the `anchorPoint` property.

Comment: Perfect! "layer.anchorPoint" was what I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, Interface Builder (the XIB/Storyboard editor part of Xcode) doesn't actually modify the anchor point of the view's layer when you change the red origin locator.  Your view will always come out of the nib with an anchor point of (0.5,0.5) regardless of the setting of the origin locator.

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.origin = CGPointMake (0.0,0.0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just sets the origin's "coordinates". I want to change what "origin" actually references. See Rob's answer. By default, "origin" refers to the upper left corner such that an "origin" point of 0,0 and a width of 35 mean's the control will extend to the right 35 pixels. That isn't what I want. I want it to extend to the LEFT 35 pixels. To do that, the "origin" itself must refer to the bottom RIGHT corner, not the default upper left. Try it in Xcode IB with an actual XIB and you'll see what I mean. Move that  "+" sign around and watch your X, Y, Width and Height values change.