# How to Adjust the height of the uilabel depending on the size of the text (number of characters)

Tags: ios, uilabel

i am fetching the content of my uilabel from the web service so i want to make the uilabel to be dynamic. I want the uilabel to adjust its width depending on how long its content.

the code i have only reduced the size of the text.

```
lblWinDesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(winDesString.frame.origin.x, winDesString.frame.origin.y + winDesString.frame.size.height, topLine.frame.size.width, lblOwnerName.frame.size.height)];
lblWinDesc.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
lblWinDesc.numberOfLines =0;
lblWinDesc.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[lblWinDesc setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
[lblWinDesc setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[contentScrollView addSubview:lblWinDesc];
```

i want the label to increase its height when the character/word reaches the maximum width of the uilabel

Comment: Your question has contradictions. Which do you wish to adjust? The width or the height?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios Dynamic sizing labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181368/ios-dynamic-sizing-labels)

Comment: i want the height to adjust. the width is fixed

Comment: r u using auto layout?

Comment: no. i code the uilabel programmatically

Comment: finally fixed it. my bad, I'm putting the code on my uiView, not the the uiviewcontroller where i set the text, thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lblWinDesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(winDesString.frame.origin.x, winDesString.frame.origin.y + winDesString.frame.size.height, topLine.frame.size.width, lblOwnerName.frame.size.height)];
  lblWinDesc.numberOfLines =0;
lblWinDesc.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[lblWinDesc setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
[lblWinDesc setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   CGSize maximumLabelSizeValue = CGSizeMake(lblWinDesc.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
CGSize expectedSubmittedByValueLabelSize = [_lblWinDesc.text sizeWithFont:_lblWinDesc.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSizeValue lineBreakMode:_lblWinDesc.lineBreakMode];
CGRect newSubmittedByValueFrame = _lblWinDesc.frame;
newSubmittedByValueFrame.origin.y=_lblWinDesc.frame.origin.y-2;
newSubmittedByValueFrame.size.height = expectedSubmittedByValueLabelSize.height+5;
[_lblWinDesc setFrame:newSubmittedByValueFrame];
[contentScrollView addSubview:lblWinDesc];
```

Comment: the label is not displaying. I'm accessing the label from my uiview, and I'm putting the code on the uiview, then the setting of the text is in the controller

Comment: i tried to put a border to see if the label is there, but its not. it disappears

Comment: you are adding Uilabel to contentScrollView. But you are saying I'm accessing the label from my uiview,.so try to get Uilabel from contentScrollView insted of UIview

Comment: `-sizeWithFont` is a deprecated method, You have to use `-boundingRectWithSize` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this..

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]};
 // NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
 // available only on ios7.0 sdk.
CGRect rect = [myString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:attributes
                                      context:nil];
//myString is the string you are getting after webservice
```

Now you can get the height of the label you want to create dynamically by using

```
rect.size.height;
```

OR
You can use the rect as the frame of your Label.
[EDIT]
Check the height of the rect, make a UILabel and set the height of the rect as the label's

```
CGFloat heightOfExpectedLabel = rect.size.height;
UILabel myLabel = [UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,heightOfExpectedLabel);
```

Comment: i tried to set the rect as frame but the label is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically increase `UILable` height you have to calculate number of lines also:

```
CGRect lblRect = self.label.frame;
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

CGRect labelRect = [self.label.text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.label.font} context:nil];

CGFloat labelHeight = labelRect.size.height;
int lines = labelHeight / 16; // This is fix height (default height) of your label
[self.label setNumberOfLines:lines];

lblRect.size.height = labelHeight;
[self.label setFrame:lblRect];
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fixed it by putting the code on my controller where i set the text. the label disappears because there is no text yet.

i simply used:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```